# How to end the workflow if the page is deleted accidentally in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem

If a workflow is running on a page and it is in Approver action step where reviewer reviews the contents and approve/rejects the contents. But someone accidentally deleted the page on which WF is running. In such scenario what should be the WF behaviour.? Is there any way to end the WF? Currently, in AEM inbox is showing "unknown resource " in red color and when approve taking action rotating (loading). The reason is there is no resource available. 
I would like to end the workflow and send the mail to Author.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box solution for this but you can write a simple script step to check for resource existence and terminate in case the resource is deleted or inaccessible. Place the script under /etc/workflows/checkresource.ecma and call it in your workflow. A pseudo script could be:

```
workflowSession.getSession().itemExists(workflowData.getPayload().toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension to i.net's solution. In order to the the script invoked, implement an event listener, which checks if nodes (of type `cq:Page`) were removed and then stop the workflows accordingly. You should be able to find the workflows with a simple query.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should lock the payload, so locking payload should be your first step in the workflow this way even if the page is moved, deleted or modified there won't be any issues or red color errors in executing workflow. Make sure to unlock the payload once all the actions are performed on the payload.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to

```
/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html
```

and click the **Instances** tab, then right click and **Terminate** an existing instance.

[image: Workflow Admin]

This UI is under Tools.